# Transform + Auto scale to new Document

Tags: adobe-photoshop

After I shoot a product photo, I am using quick selection tool to select only the product, click refine edge, cut + paste into new document that must be 2000 x 2000 pixels white background. When I paste into that new document ofcourse that the image cut before it is bigger than the size of the new document ( 2000x2000 ). 
Is there a keyboard shortcut to automatically transform to the scale of the new document ? I am using Ctr + T, hold Shift and drag picture from corners. But I am asking for a shortcut to do that faster. I have hundreds of photos.

Thank you !
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your new document is always the same width/height, you can create an **[action](http://www.crispphotoworks.com/what-are-photoshop-actions-and-how-do-you-use-them/)** to transform it automatically.

```
Windows > Actions
```

Start recording your action after you paste your image. Record the resize to 2000px. Then when you paste a new one, play the action and it will automatically scale to the right proportions.

You can also automate the saving / exporting.

Comment: Thinking it was a keyb. command to do fast the resize to 2000 px after paste it.

Comment: You can create a shortcut to execute the last action recorded. Check the [instructions here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/play-action-shortcut/).

Comment: It didn't work. It only works for the picture I am creating the action. For other photo the final result is way out of my document size. Must be a keyboard shortcut for fit image.